# Issues with Index Match Match and Userform in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am trying to run code to use sap_a and sap_b (both text boxes in a userform) to look up the variable 'Run'. I wrote the code so that the person entering the sap_a and sap_b values could enter the values in either box and the 'Run' variable would be found, which is why ErrorCheck1 exists. ErrorCheck2 exists simply to provide a message if the values in sap_a/b are unable to be matched with a 'Run' variable. The issue I'm having is that this code generates a 'Run' value even when one of the sap_a or sap_b values is not correct (i.e. sap_a is a value that does exist in the spreadsheet, sap_b is a fake value not existing in the spreadsheet, and a 'Run' variable is still produced). Do you have any input specifically regarding issues with my code or any issues you see? Code is attached.

Thank you!

```
Private Sub SearchButtonTEST_Click()
Dim sap_a As Variant
Dim sap_b As Variant
Dim Run_ As Variant

Sheets("R_Database Sheet").Activate

sap_a = textbox5.Value
sap_b = textbox8.Value

If sap_a = "" And sap_b = "" Then
    Run_ = ""
        Let textbox1.Text = Run_
  Msgbox "Must enter SAP Codes in SAP # A and SAP # B to search."

Exit Sub

Else

Check1:
On Error GoTo ErrorCheck1

    Run_ = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("R_Database Sheet").Range("A:A"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CLng((sap_a)), Sheets("R_Database Sheet").Range("E:E"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CLng((sap_b)), Sheets("R_database sheet").Range("H:H"), 0)))
    Let textbox1.Text = Run_

Check2:

On Error GoTo ErrorCheck2

    Run_ = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("R_Database Sheet").Range("A:A"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CLng((sap_b)), Sheets("R_Database Sheet").Range("E:E"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CLng((sap_a)), Sheets("R_database sheet").Range("H:H"), 0)))
    Let textbox1.Text = Run_

Exit Sub

Check3:
Msgbox "No data found for specified SAP #'s."

End If

Exit Sub

ErrorCheck1:
Resume Check2

ErrorCheck2:
Resume Check3

End Sub
```

Comment: Match takes at most 3 arguments - you seem to be supplying more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will be easier to manage if you drop the `Worksheetfunction` and just use `Application.Match`

If you include the `worksheetfunction` then a run-time error is raised if there's no match (requiring tricky error handling).  If you drop it, then a no-match just returns an *error value* which you can test using `IsError()`.  Personally I find this much easier to manage.

```
Private Sub SearchButtonTEST_Click()

    Dim sap_a As Variant, sap_b As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet, mA, mB

    Set ws = Sheets("R_Database Sheet")

    sap_a = Trim(textbox5.Value)
    sap_b = Trim(textbox8.Value)

    If sap_a = "" And sap_b = "" Then
        textbox1.Text = ""
        MsgBox "Must enter SAP Codes in SAP # A and SAP # B to search."
        Exit Sub
    Else

        mA = Application.Match(CLng(sap_a), ws.Range("E:E"), 0)
        mB = Application.Match(CLng(sap_b), ws.Range("H:H"), 0)

        If Not IsError(mA) Then
            textbox1.Text = ws.Cells(mA, "A")
        ElseIf Not IsError(mB) Then
            textbox1.Text = ws.Cells(mB, "A")
        Else
            textbox1.Text = "Not found!"
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked wonderfully. Thank you for taking the time to help!